# Angular child component not updating after change detection

Tags: angular

Perhaps I have the wrong setup from the beginning, but I'm having an issue with a child component `@Input` decorator not updating after the parent's variable has changed. My problem is that the parent's variable is actually getting updated in another child's component that is inherited from the parent.

#### Sub View Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'sub-view',
  templateUrl: './sub-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sub-view.component.scss']
})
export class SubViewComponent {
  @Input() links;
  ...
}
```

#### Parent Component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {
  roleLinks:any;

  constructor() {}
  ...
}
```

#### Parent View

```html
<sub-view 
    [links]="roleLinks" 
></sub-view>
```

#### Child Component #1

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child1.component.scss']
})
export class Child1Component extends ParentComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.roleLinks = [
      {key:'a',val:'A'},
      {key:'b',val:'B'}
    ];
  }
  ...
}
```

I have `Child1Component extends ParentComponent` because the idea is that I'll have a `Child2`, `Child3` etc. Each child will have a lot of shared components with `Parent`

So the `SubView` will only need to be bound to `Parent` and then each `Child` Component will be able to have it's own `links`

However, I cannot get the `links` to update in `SubView`
Looking at other SO Q/A's, I have tried the following:

- adding `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to `SubView`
- adding `detectChanges()` from `ChangeDetectorRef` to `SubView`
- adding `markForCheck()` from `ChangeDetectorRef` to `SubView`

And neither of them worked. `links` is always `undefined` inside `SubView` even though I can see that when it is changed inside `Child` the changes are actually making it down to `Parent` however `SubView` is just not detecting the changes

It may be worth noting that I have each `Child` component in a nested `<router-outlet>` within `Parent` Component.

```
-App
  <router-outlet>
    +Page1
    +Page2
    -Parent
      +SubView
      <router-outlet>
        +Child1
        +Child2
        +...
      +OtherSubView
```

### StackBlitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2qemh

Comment: The Parent passes its roleLinks to the Subview. Bu the parent's roleLinks is an empty array. The fact that another, completely dfferent component, which has its own roleLinks array, populates its own array with two links won't have any impact on the roleLinks array of the Parent component instance. Toyota extends Car, but that doesn't mean that when a specific Toyota car has two passengers, all cars have the two same passengers.

Comment: No, not at all. You're completely misunderstanding inheritance.

Comment: Did  you try to add ngIf? <sub-view *ngIf="roleLinks" [links]="roleLinks"></sub-view>

Comment: What is the router outlet doing in this case (or rather, what is it supposed to do)? Also, is it possible to make a stackblitz of this (it's rather complicated otherwise)

Comment: @JBNizet I added a stackblitz to show the inheritance.

Comment: I updated it for you to demonstrate you that each component instance has its own array: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqyag5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild2%2Fchild2.component.html

Comment: @JBNizet please see the updated stackblitz. I call `super.ngOnInit()` in each child which calls Base `onInit()` to log the `roleLinks`. After each child is initialized, the Base `roleLinks` is equal to that of what was assigned in each Child

Comment: I'm looking at your stackblitz. There does not appear to be any place where the value of `links` is assigned to.

Comment: in `base.component.html` I am binding `[links]="roleLinks"`

Comment: No, it isn't. Again, you're not understanding inheritance and polymorphism. `this` is the current **object**. So, when you log `this.roleLinks` from inside the base's ngOnInit method, and this method is in fact called on an instance of Child1, `this` is the Child1 instance, and `this.roleLinks` is the role links of the Child1 instance. This is fundamental OO stuff. If you have an instance variable (roleLinks) defined in a class, and you create 3 instances of that class, each instance has its own value of this instance variable.

Comment: @amallard - would you mind restating the problem in terms of what it is you are trying to achieve (from a requirements standpoint)? I can't interpret the design intent from the code, and the discussion has not proven to be fruitful either.

Comment: See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6brj5f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts for a (hopefully) helpful demonstration of how inheritance and objects works. But really, you need to take a step back and learn about the fundamentals of objects.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation. Despite literally creating a `Base Class`, I didn't really associate an OO-class inside an Angular app, thus wasn't thinking about the difference between instance variable and static variable. I ended up using the shared service after all as suggested by @theMayer. Thank you both for your explanations

Answer (score 2):

So, I think the problem is that you are not assigning the `roleLinks` property in the parent component, but rather in the child component (where it is never used).

If you have the following template for parentComponent

```
<childComponent [links]="roleLinks></childComponent>
```

Then `roleLinks` will be assigned from the parent component to the child component. Class-based inheritance is irrelevant for assigning the `roleLinks` property on the original parent item.

Instead, you will need to assign this property directly, or, if you need state to be shared between parent and child, create an [angular service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) with the data you need and inject it into both.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a shared service. I figured the inheritance would suffice. I can see that when `Child` updates `roleLinks` it is in fact updating in `Parent`'s `roleLinks` They are one in the same. And on `Parent` component initialization, it is sending `roleLinks` to `SubView`. The problem is that `Parent` is sending `roleLinks` to `SubView` (which is undefined on initialization) before `Child` sends it up to `Parent`

Comment: No, they aren't the same. The only way they would be the same is if they were static. Are you using the debugger correctly? Also, even if you had wired it up to the same property, this is not the correct way to implement a two-way data binding.

Comment: I `console.log(this.roleLinks)` from both `Parent` and `Child`. At the end of `Child` init, I call `Parent` init again (with console.log) and it does show the values that I assigend in `Child`. So calling `console.log(this.roleLinks)` from `Parent` is showing the values I assigned from `Child`

Comment: See update for StackBlitz link. Open the console, click on Base button. See that roleLinks is undefined. Then click Child1. See that roleLinks is now populated with the same roleLinks assigned from Child1. Then click Child2. Same thing. Base roleLinks is getting populated from the roleLinks in Children that extend Parent.